# Plotting velocity fields in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I need to know how to plot a velocity field in QGIS 3.6. 
I have u, v and magnitude data in a CSV file.

I installed some plugins such as Crayfish, vector field calc, contour plugin, point sampling tool to calculate velocity fields. But still I couldn't do it. 
I found some tutorials on how to do it in QGIS 2.**. According to the tutorial I need Vector Field Renderer plugin as well. However, in QGIS 3.6 that plugin is not available. How can I proceed this further.

Problem solved using symbol library and some edits on csv files. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#the-vector-field-marker

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Vector field markers are in the standard symbol library, no plugin needed: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#the-vector-field-marker

Comment: Thank you. It worked well. I used symbol library and draw them.